# Resource Dictionary Merging for each UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

For each UserControl in my project.
I add to the XAML for merging dictionaries:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

It is necessary to have available customized styles and colors.

Tell me is it correct to do so?
It does not reduce the performance?

Comment: if you want this dictionary across project then why you are adding in each Usercontrol.you should add in App.XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are resolved by traversing up the logical tree. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) -

> 1. The lookup process checks for the requested key within the resource dictionary defined by the element that sets the property.
> 2. The lookup process then traverses the logical tree upward, to the parent element and its resource dictionary. This continues until the
>      root element is reached.
> 3. Next, application resources are checked. Application resources are those resources within the resource dictionary that is defined by the
>      Application object for your WPF application.

As mentioned in point 3 above, resource lookup will finally search it in application resources. So you don't need to add same resource in all UserControls. You can simply put them in one place from where every UserControl can have access to resources.

**In short App.xaml is right place to put merged resource dictionaries which are required across all user controls.**